# Casting (convert) structure to array of bits: bit-stream type error

Tags: types, casting, system-verilog, bitstream

In `systemverilog LRM`, there is a sample code to explain casting.
When I try this code, there is an error.

```
typedef struct {
   bit isfloat;
   union { int i; shortreal f; } n; // anonymous type
} tagged_st; // named structure

typedef bit [$bits(tagged_st) - 1 : 0] tagbits;
tagged_st a [7:0]; // unpacked array of structures
tagbits t = tagbits'(a[3]); / convert structure to array of bits
a[4] = tagged_st'(t); // convert array of bits back to structure
```

- First, for `$bits()` function, compiler says **`the argument of the system function call was not of bit-stream type.`**
- Second, when assign `a[3]` with a type casting of `tagbits`, it says **`The source of the target of the bit-stream casting is not of bit-stream type`**
  My understanding is that, structure and unpacked array are also bit-stream type.
  Hope to know what is a point I missed.`(cadence 18.09-006)`

Answer (score 2):

An unpacked *union* is not a bitstream type. From the LRM,

> By default, a union is unpacked, meaning there is no required
>   representation for how members of the union are stored

This means you cannot know how many bits are represented.

Comment: Yes, in LRM, there is what you answer but for above example, there is also description that “The size of union in bits is the size of its largest member”.

Comment: This is a reported problem example with the LRM. A real/shortreal is not a bit-stream type, and therefore cannot be used with $bits.